# Is there a way to set how many characters ReadString will read?

Tags: c#

What I want to do is set the amount of characters `BinaryReader.ReadString()` reads to 1. I have this in a file

`43 00 49 00 54 00 52 00 41` = `C I t r a`

obviously I can make it read `C I t r a` by just doing `BinaryReader.ReadString()` but instead what I want to do is remove the spaces between the letters and make it check to see if there are any letters after the `a`. This is what I have now

```
//OF_name is the offset at which the name begins at
//sins there is a space between each letter, I do "I += 2"
for (int i = OF_name; i <= br.BaseStream.Length; i += 2)
{
    br.BaseStream.Position = i;
    byte check = br.ReadByte();
    if (check == 0) break; //the file which contains the string always has a 7 byte space between the name bytes and the rest of the data.
    string a = br.ReadByte().ToString(); //forgot that this just makes it be represented as a string (byte 43 => string "43" not "C")
}
```

Is there a way to make ReadString() read 1 character at a time instead of 7 so it would read `C` then `I` then `t` and so on? or is there a way to do it as I do but instead of converting `byte 43` to `string "43"` it would convert `byte 43` to `string "C"`?

Comment: Read the number of _bytes_ you need, then pass that to an Encoding of choice. You probably have to read an even amount, or append another 0 byte, then decode using UTF-16 (`Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes)`).

Comment: Those are not spaces. You need to [read a string in little-endian UTF-16 encoding with BinaryReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082280/).