# Read html file as string in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to read a html file and parse the content to a string

From this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    Index
</body>
</html>
```

To an output like this

```
$stringValue = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\"\"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">"...
```

I've tried with `$stringValue = $htmlFile | ConvertTo-Json` but it transforms some characters into new codes (> = `u003e`) where I want to keep the special characters intact.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you trying parsing the content as UTF-16 in the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below command to get the content of html file and that you can store in any string variable like below.

```
[string]$Datas = Get-Content [HTML_file_Location]
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked:)

Answer (score 0):

Try to read it as UTF-16 and see if output is passed through as desired. This answer shows how to read it as UTF-16.

[Reading a "string in little-endian UTF-16 encoding" with BinaryReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082280/reading-a-string-in-little-endian-utf-16-encoding-with-binaryreader)